# Increment user's points based on increase in user's posts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, linq, linq-to-entities

**I have a simple user with following feilds----**

```
   public class User
    { 
      public User()
      {
       this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
       }
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    piblic int point {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**then, i have a post table corresponding to user something like this---**

```
 public class Post
 { 
   public Post()
   {
      public int PostId { get; set; }
      public string Message { get; set; }
      public int PostedBy { get; set; }
      public virtual User User { get; set; }
   }
 }
```

**now, There is a one to many relationship between user and posts table. 1 user can have multiple posts.Now, i want to increase user's points based on user's post increment in posts Table.Suppose, a user posted 5 posts on some issues then i want to increment his points from 0 to 25 means on per posts, an increment of 5.**
What i have tried so far is this query-----

```
    from p in Posts
    join u in UserProfiles
    on p.PostedBy equals u.UserId
    where p.PostedBy == 1
    group p by p.PostedBy into dups 
    let totalcount = dups.Count()
    select totalcount
```

1>Now, i would like to assign this total count value(output) to User's point column in the UserProfilesTable and save that value to the database.
Many many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Don't you just need to multiply the count by 5?

Comment: @juharr  nope, if used multiplying then if posts.count is 3 then it output will be 25.i just want to increase the counter value by 5 on per post's increase

Comment: If the count is 3 and you multiple by 5 the output would be 15.  Why do you think it would be 25?  It seems like if each post is worth 5 points then your total points is just the count time 5.  If that's not correct can you explain why?

Comment: @juharr Ohhh sorry guy u Were right thnks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class User
{ 
    public User()
    {
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int point {get { return this.Posts.Count*5; } }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a LINQ query:

```
var user = db.UserProfiles.Select(up=> new User {
  UserId=up.UserId,
  UserName=up.UserName,
  Password=up.Password, //Really?
  point=up.Posts.Count()*5,
  });
```

Comment: May be this may fits here but in reality, I have a scenario where user's points increased on increasing number of posts, comments, likes, etc etc.I would like to have Linq Approach with nested queries. Btw many many thanks for ur help. @Robert McKee

Comment: I've updated the answer with a LINQ query that should work for you, assuming you have the normal navigation properties set up.

Comment: can u tell me one more thing how to increase user's point based on increase in number of comments on his posts. how to accomodate that too. that will solve all my problems. thanks in advance

Comment: `point=up.Posts.Count()*5+up.Posts.Sum(p=>p.Comments.Count())`